# Drawing polygon using parts of existing polyline in ArcGIS editing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I use AcrGIS 10.2, and I met a problem about drawing a polygon "effectively".

[image: Fig.1]

There is an existing line (see above). I want to draw a polygon whose part of the border is this polyline. I can catch every vertex of the line to make the polygopn match with the polyline. But this method may become impossible (and tiring) when this existing line has many turning points.

Is there some useful method to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the trace feature available in the editor bar. First click one point at the edge of the line. Then select the trace feature than click again at the edge point on the line and than simply roll you mouse pointer over the line. At the end point of the line click and than select the "straight segment" available in the editor bar to again continue drawing your polygon outside the line.